# Importing a JS file on Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I created a simple file called `main.js`. In this file, i defined a function:

```
function hello(){
  console.log('hello')
}
```

Now i'm trying to import the file on a template and call the function from there. Here is what i tried:

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" charset="{% static 'main.js' %}">
hello()
</script>
```

But this is giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
```

Why is this happening? Am i not importing the file? This is where **main.js** is located:

```
static -> main.js
```

And here is how my static directory is defined on Django:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My static directory contains a lot of other files and i'm not having problems with those; can someone help me find what i'm doing wrong with this one? Every advice is appreciated

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem in loading js file. Use `src` attribute to load js file. Below is the updated html code.

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    hello()
</script>
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Helped me indeed. Had no idea i was missing on such a simple thing! Thank you a lot! Give me 3 minutes to accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly confirm if you have this line on top of your html file.
`{% load static %}` This will load static files.

Comment: Yes, i'm using that tag; added it now to my question

Comment: you're using charset instead of src